# uwp acrylic tint color black appears dark gray

Tags: xaml, uwp, fluent-design, acrylic-material

In my uwp app I am trying to use the Acrylic Brush, I made a custom one because the default ones are not working for me. But if you notice here I have attached image from Microsoft docs and on right side is window of my app showing acrylic completely different on same background.

[image: comparing]

**Code**

```
 <AcrylicBrush
                            x:Key="AppBackgroundAcrylicBrush"
                            BackgroundSource="HostBackdrop"
                            FallbackColor="Black"
                            TintColor="Black"
                            TintLuminosityOpacity="0.1"
                            TintOpacity="1" />
```

After that I tried luminosity to be 0.9 and now it looks dark grayish. But I want it to look **jet black** color Acrylic with small transparency. Basically I want it to look like as the image shows on left side as in Microsoft docs with 10% luminosity and 100% tint opacity.

[image]

**Code**

```
   <AcrylicBrush
                            x:Key="AppBackgroundAcrylicBrush"
                            BackgroundSource="HostBackdrop"
                            FallbackColor="Black"
                            TintColor="Black"
                            TintLuminosityOpacity="0.9"
                            TintOpacity="1" />
```

Docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/style/acrylic

Answer (score 1):

> Basically I want it to look like as the image showson left side as in microsoft docs with 10% luminosity and 100 % tint opacity.

**Update**

Base on the testing, `TintLuminosityOpacity` 0.9 and TintOpacity 1.0 could render you mentioned jet black color `AcrylicBrush`.  But that is not conformity with document. And the `AcrylicBrush` looks dark gray. It is strange, I will report to related team. Currently, please try use the following to replace.

```
<AcrylicBrush
    x:Key="CustomAcrylicBrush"
    BackgroundSource="Backdrop"
    FallbackColor="Black"
    TintColor="Black"
    TintLuminosityOpacity="1.0"
    TintOpacity="1"
    />
```

Comment: not sure which reference u used for testing but as u can see in 2nd screenshot I posted above that has 0.9 Luminosity and opacity=1 but it is still grayish, and when I make luminosity 1.0 it just stops being transparent and becomes opaque dark gray color. same with white color, I am nt able to achieve pure white in light theme using same values. with color as white.

Comment: when u said the document screenshot has little chromatism , does that mean I cannot achieve those colors in reality ?

Comment: This behavior is every strange, I will report it, thanks for your feed back.

Comment: thankyou for reporting it to the right team, where can I follow progress on this ?